# Command Prompt/Batch - rename multiple files with sequential numbering of same number of digits

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt, batch-rename

I always have taken many photos that need to rename that with desired prefix and number, say I have the following photos

> IMG_1933.JPG
>   IMG_1934.JPG
>   IMG_1935.JPG
>   IMG_1936.JPG
>   IMG_1937.JPG

Then I want to run a batch file to change them to:

> Goodlooking 0098.jpg
>   Goodlooking 0099.jpg
>   Goodlooking 0100.jpg
>   Goodlooking 0101.jpg
>   Goodlooking 0102.jpg

I have read some answers here but cannot keep the leading zero while keeping the same number of digits when the number goes from 99 to 100, or 999 to 1000. Like the following:

```
@echo off  
pushd %~dp0  
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion  

set filename=Goodlooking 00  
set Num=98  
for /r %%i in (*.jpg) do (  
    ren "%%i" "%filename%!Num!.jpg"  
    set /a Num+=1  
)
```

The above codes can do most of the works, but cannot keep the number of digits.

That means I need to setup two variables, 1) the prefix; 2) the starting number, then keep the same number of digits.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
@echo off  
pushd %~dp0  
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion  

set "filename=Goodlooking"

set Num=10098
for /r %%i in (*.jpg) do (
    ren "%%~i" "%filename% !Num:~1!%%~xi"
    set /a Num+=1
)
```

We need to consider octal values, therefore we add `1` to the `num` then simply get rid of it when renaming.

to understand the problem with octal values you can open `cmd.exe` and run this to see the result:

```
set /a num=0098
```